# How do I define a class in MATLAB that uses methods defined in separate files (in an @-folder)?

Tags: class, matlab, methods, directory-structure

I would like to define a class in one file, and its methods in several other files.

Apparently, the way to do this is to create a subfolder named `@<ClassName>`in the class folder, and to put all the method files in the so-called "@-folder".

However, once I've made the @-folder, I'm not sure what to put in the class-definition file to make it aware of the methods in the @-folder.

```
classdef myClass

    properties
        myProperty = 0;
    end

    methods
        %#
        %# --- What goes here? --- 
        %#
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare the function signature without the `function` keyword, and **with a semicolon at the end.**

```
classdef myClass

    properties
        myProperty = 0;
    end

    methods
        retval = my_function ( arguments );
    end
end
```

Then MATLAB will go looking for a file called `../@MyClass/my_function.m`.

Comment: I *think* this is only required if you wish to my 'my_function' have non-default access - i.e. you could have declared 'my_function' to be private/static etc.

Comment: I don't think you do need a semicolon. Works fine for me without.

Comment: @Li-aungYip Thank you. Now for some reason I'm getting an error when I use one of the methods, saying there's "too many input arguments", even though there is exactly the right number... but I suppose that's a different question.